# Magento 2.4.5: How to Add some new text links in the Copyright row of the Magento Blank theme Footer

Tags: footer-links, magento2.4.5

I'm new and using MAGENTO 2.4.5 and a Magento blank theme. I wanted to add some new text links in the Copyright row of the Magento Blank theme Footer
 
How can I do that? I have tried several ways, but nothing works.

I want the frontend copyright footer to change from this:

Copyright © 2013-present Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.

to become this:
Copyright © 2013-present Ourcompany, Inc. All rights reserved. <a href=“https://beian.com">beian

I try to create a static block (Identifier:
copyright_footer_links_block )for our custom HTML code as below:
Copyright © 2013-present Ourcompany, Inc. All rights reserved. <a href=“https://beian.com">beian

then:
Copy copyright.phtml file in our theme

vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/copyright.phtml

to
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/copyright.phtml

Now I do not know how to call our static block in copyright.phtml file to add custom text below copyright

I try below Method: (edit copyright.phtml (app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/copyright.phtml)in Xcode then save)
[image: copyright.phtml]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override the copyright.phtml file to add the block to the page, you can extend the layout xml and add the block there.

Create/edit the file at `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer.copyright.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">copyright_footer_links_block</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <move element="footer.copyright.links" destination="footer-container" after="copyright" />
    </body>
</page>
```

That's based on the original theme layout at `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`, you may need to change the `destination` parameter if your theme moved the copyright element to a different container.